Serverside dynamically addClass Datatable
NOTE - Datatable serverside processing with MySql database
and the code is as follows
$(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#userDataList').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "fetchData.php",
        
stateSave: 'true',

    });
});

Also the table / page available at
http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/index-old.html
1)
How to add a class to all
a) even rows dynamically.
b) odd columns dynamically.
2)
How to add a class with a button click to each odd rows with serverside processing with datatable ?
For example
$('tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('whatever'); 

the above code is useful to add the code for the current page only.
But when we make a change like pagination / search / next page / order then the added class will disappears.
Also try something like
dt.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
      var row = dt.row(this).node();
      if ( rowIdx % 2 === 0 ) {
          $( 'td:eq(3)', row ).addClass("yellow");
      }                
});

the above code also applies /  works on the current page only.

Assuming there's no additional logic (eg when value<0 then add class red), you can do the same with css:  eg table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(4) https://jsfiddle.net/vkcodtry/ (using Vincent's fiddle).

i use a button click to do that function. available at http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/

You should add your JS code on events, you can use the draw.dt event which is triggered every time the data is rendered, more information: https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw
var dt = new DataTable('#myTable');
 
dt.on('draw', function () {
   dt.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
      var row = dt.row(this).node();
      if ( rowIdx % 2 === 0 ) {
         $( 'td:eq(3)', row ).addClass("yellow");
      }                
   });
});

Not so sure about the syntax. Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7at8dgz/2/

but it works on the current page only.

@varghese check at the fiddle I added in my answer, the event is triggered on pagination also

Vincent - how to integrate it with at http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/

vincent - or how to integrate it with at http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/index-old.html  i am a beginner in serverside and datatables. so knowledge is very low average.

Vincent - or how your code can integrate with my basic code as $(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('#userDataList').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "fetchData.php",
stateSave: 'true',
});


@varghese the difference between your code and this is that this is inside dt.on("draw", so runs every time datatables (re-)draws the table, including paging and sorting.

Vincent - i mention 'table' instead 'dt'. but i try your code as well but not working with my code. also don't know why ? the reason is my knowledge is limited.

@varghese please create a fiddle with all your code, your question is not clear

vincent - my basic code as $(document).ready(function(){ var table = $('#userDataList').DataTable({ "processing": true, "serverSide": true, "ajax": "fetchData.php", stateSave: 'true', });  at http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/index-old.html  Here how can i add a class to all 1) even rows and 2) odd columns dynamically. i don't know how to use fiddle with jquery,  php scripts and mysql database there.
